# Installation bind from sources

Tags: linux, dns, bind, fedora

I trying to install bind from sources on Fedora 24. I have a big problem. After installation, directory like `/var/named` or file `named.conf` does not exist. I was trying to create it manually but it didn't work too.

And my question is: where can i get that files? I know that if i install bind via `yum`, those files will be created properly, but then bind won't be in the newest version.

Comment: Check to spec file of `bind` in Fedora. It will help you to understand what is done special there.

Comment: Why do you need the newest version of BIND?